# Cube Calculation - MDX - Compare Date to Another Date from Date Dimension

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

I am trying to create a calculation measure to compare revenue from one date to last year's equivalent date.

I have this "last year's equivalent date" stored in my date dimension.

So for example, my fact table of DailySummary has a measure of TotalRevenue and it is granular by date. If I wanted to show today's revenue (12/06/2019), the equivalent date from last year that is stored in the Date dimension would be 12/07/2018. I would want to show both those day's revenue side by side. I would then create other measures, like growth.

I am sure it is obvious, but if it helps, the DailySummary fact and the Date dimension are joined by the date, so today's date, not the last year equivalent.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense or if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to use the PreviousPeriod MDX function.